# Run Nestjs API project on VPS Hosting of Hostgator

Tags: nestjs, subdomain, vps, dedicated-server, dedicated-hosting

i have developed a site using angular as frontend and nestjs as backend for api and firebase firestore as database.
my project was running fine on localhost but when i deployed it to my hosting, the angular project worked fine.
the problem started when i deployed nestjs project on my subdomain for example exampleapi.com
[page appears like this when i visit my domain url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFu5P.png)

Hosting i purchased is of Hostgator Snappy 2000 OR dedicated Server.

Then i searched and found that server needs t install nodejs. i contact support team and they installed nodejs on my server. then i followed this url
[this one first](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-22-04)
and this one also (https://medium.com/swlh/deploy-nest-js-app-with-postgres-in-vps-e1ce4abd2cad)

[this one also](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-install-and-configure-nginx-on-centos-7)

now i am just stuck both angular url example.com and exampleapi.com give me 404 page like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JRKL.png)

Now i dont know what to do with this issue. my user was root for reference.
please help. there is nothing much data for this.
i used terminal and ran some commands using YUM and Centos is OS i guess.
any help is apppreciated

i was expecting that like angular project my nestjs project would run fine but it gives nothing